# Ruby: Binding a listening socket to a specific interface

Tags: ruby

I want to create a TCP socket that listens only on a specific interface (say, eth0).  How can I do this?  I've tried browsing through the Socket API, but I may not be understanding things properly.

Here is my listen method so far:

```
def listen
  socket = TCPServer.open($port)
  while $looping do
    Thread.start(socket.accept) do |server|
      response = server.read
      puts "Command received: #{response}"
      if sanitize(response)
        execute(response)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get the IP of the network interface you want to listen on and pass it as the first parameter to `TCPServer.new`. There is no way that I know of to specify the interface by name besides parsing the output of `%x(ifconfig <interface> | grep inet)`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I did the following:

socket = TCPServer.new("127.0.0.1", $port)

For the record, TCPServer.open seems to work the exact same way.